# Why is my rendered image back?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, import

I am trying to render a model that I didn't make myself, and the result is a black shape, while the 3D view is presenting the textures correctly.

[image]

(is this is considered NSFW, let me know, I'll blur something!)

Here's what the Object Data panel looks like:

[image]

I've seen similar questions, but the Object Data textures weren't the same as what I have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have no lights in the file (and in the layer).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I added lights and now it's not black anymore... But gray (no textures). Might be another question unless I figure it out! Thanks